# Erlang case statement

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, erl

I have the following Erlang code and it is giving the warning as follows, when i try to compile it, but that make sense. function need two arguments, but i need to patten match "everything else" rather x, y or z.

```
-module(crop).
-export([fall_velocity/2]).

fall_velocity(P, D) when D >= 0 ->
case P of
x -> math:sqrt(2 * 9.8 * D);
y -> math:sqrt(2 * 1.6 * D);
z -> math:sqrt(2 * 3.71 * D);
(_)-> io:format("no match:~p~n")
end.

crop.erl:9: Warning: wrong number of arguments in format call.
```

I was trying an anonymous variable after io:format, but still it is not happy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the format you use ~p. It means -- print value. So  you must specify what value to print.

last line of case must be

```
_ -> io:format("no match ~p~n",[P])
```

Besides, io:format returms 'ok'. So if P is not x y or z, your function will return 'ok' instead of numeric value. I would suggest to return tagged value to separate correct and error returns. Kind of

```
fall_velocity(P, D) when D >= 0 ->
case P of
x -> {ok,math:sqrt(2 * 9.8 * D)};
y -> {ok,math:sqrt(2 * 1.6 * D)};
z -> {ok,math:sqrt(2 * 3.71 * D)};
Otherwise-> io:format("no match:~p~n",[Otherwise]),
            {error, "coordinate is not x y or z"}
end.
```

Comment: I'd throw an exception, or maybe just don't even check for anything else than x,y,z. Erlang fails comprehensibly, no need to overdo it.

Comment: right. But if do not check, you can get an error somewhere much later than invoking function.  {ok,R} = fall_velocity(A,B) could point an error earlier.

Comment: In fact, it depends on who calls the function. If the function is part of an API, tagged values are indeed welcome. But if the function is an internal part deep inside your codebase, you end up having case statements everywhere, continuously error-checking your own code, which is a needless hassle. Just let it fail.

Comment: It is one of those things which are easy to check so "they" decided to add a warning check for it. It is only a warning so if you decide to ignore then you will get an error when you run the code.

Answer (score 3):

To make the comments to the other answer explicit, this is how I would write that function:

```
-module(crop).
-export([fall_velocity/2]).

fall_velocity(P, D) when D >= 0 ->
    case P of
        x -> math:sqrt(2 * 9.8 * D);
        y -> math:sqrt(2 * 1.6 * D);
        z -> math:sqrt(2 * 3.71 * D)
    end.
```

That is, *don't* handle the incorrect argument in your case expression.  If someone passes `foo` as an argument, you'll get the error `{case_clause, foo}` along with a stacktrace that points to this function *and* its caller.  This also means that this function cannot leak incorrect values into the rest of the code as a result of being called with incorrect arguments.

Returning `{ok, Result} | {error, Error}` as in the other answer is equally valid.  You'll need to choose the variant that fits your case best.